# PHP Image Magick images with poor quality when converting them into a PDF

Tags: php, imagemagick, dompdf

My client has an option in its page where he can export a group of files (images and other PFDs) into a new PDF.

For parsing the selected PDFs I am using Image Magick so, I go over each page of the PDF and I create a new image.

```
        $im = new Imagick($file);
        $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
        $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

        $pagesNumber = $im->getNumberImages();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $pagesNumber; $i++) {
            $im->setIteratorIndex($i);

            $imagePath = $tempFolder . '/page-' . $i . '.jpg';
            $this->tempParsedPdf[] = $imagePath;

            $im->writeImage($imagePath);
        }
```

After creating all the images I render them on an HTML template which is parsed into a PDF using `dompdf`. When I open the PDF I see that the images created from the selected PDF have a poor quality and the text is blurred.

I do not know if there is any other way or something I am missing for creating the images with a better definition.

Comment: When reading the PDF, set the density/resolution to a higher value than the default 72, say 150 or 300, before reading the PDF to render it.

Comment: Try using [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) for DOM to PDF

Comment: I removed the code for processing the PDF using Image Magick and added a PDF merger and it works really good.